# HTML5/CSS Browser malfunctioning

Tags: css, html, height, width, viewport

I just put my website live. It's displaying differently than when I tested it to begin with. The site is http://www.se7enservice.com. It's my site, so no spam. Pictures won't show, but not needed here.

When you look at this JSFiddle, you can see that my 'About' sections looks normal.
https://jsfiddle.net/blackRob4953/z8qn39nj/

However, when you go to the actual live webpage, the margins of the words are lowered. This is only happening on the 'About' and 'Contact Us' Page.

**Can anyone explain to me why this is happening, and how to fix it?**

**Ignore this style code below, it's the same in the JSFiddle, but I have to post code in order to paste the link...

```
body{
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;

-webkit-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;

-webkit-justify-content: center; 
justify-content: center; 

margin: 0 !important;
min-height:100vh;
min-width: 1280px;
width: 100vw;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `min-height: 200vh` from `#content{}`

Comment: Thanks! such a simple fix..... one of those I just needed another pair of eyes on ha. appreciate it